# Altering a CASE statement to handle NULL values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm in need of help modifying an existing case statement that has to be changed to accommodate the possibility of a null value.

Currently, the statement is as follows:

```
CASE WHEN 
  DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer) > 0 THEN 
   DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer 
  ELSE NULL END 
AS Days_Past_Due
```

I just want to change the existing CASE statement to be able to handle a null table.OpenDate field, returning a NULL as Days_Past_Due. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of making your expression **more** complex, you should simplify it:

```
CASE WHEN 
  DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer) > 0 THEN 
  DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer 
  END 
AS Days_Past_Due
```

1. CASE .. without an ELSE implicitly returns NULL for the ELSE branch.
2. Datediff with either or both dates being NULL return NULL. No special magic required.  Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5682/0)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
CASE 
  WHEN table.OpenDate IS NULL THEN NULL
  WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer) > 0 THEN 
   DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer 
  ELSE NULL 
END AS Days_Past_Due
```

Comment: Thank you, will I need to specify when OpenDate is NOT NULL as well? For example: CASE WHEN table.OpenDate IS NOT NULL AND DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer WHEN table.OpenDate IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE NULL END As Days_Past_Due

Answer (score 0):

--Add a line to the CASE to handle a NULL table.OpenDate and render it as NULL

```
CASE
 WHEN DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer 
 WHEN table.OpenDate IS NULL THEN NULL
 ELSE NULL
END 
AS Days_Past_Due
```

Comment: Thank you, will I need to specify when OpenDate is NOT NULL as well? For example:
    CASE
    WHEN table.OpenDate IS NOT NULL AND DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer) > 0 THEN DATEDIFF(dd, table.OpenDate, GetDate()) - table.Days_as_Integer
    WHEN table.OpenDate IS NULL THEN NULL
    ELSE NULL
END
As Days_Past_Due